# What is the best TDD approach for writing a test case for my DAO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tdd

I am having a hard time writing some test cases right now as I am new to TDD. For example, I have this dao method,

```
public Customer getById(Long id) {
    if (id < 1L) {
        return null;
    }
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("id", id);

    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from customer where id = :id", params, new RowMapper<Customer>() {

        public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return createCustomerFromResultSet(rs);
        }
    });
}
```

which I wish to test negatively. The negative test case,

```
@Test
public void getByIdNegative() throws Exception {
    Customer customer = customerDao.getById(-1L);
    log.debug("Customer retrieved: " + customer);
    assertNull(customer);
}
```

throws an exception so I wrote the if clause seen above in the dao method to resolve it but it doesn't seem like this is the right way. Should I expect an exception? Handle it? If so at which layer and how? Is the negative test in this case even necessary or just overkill? These are some questions in my mind right now. I would like to know how to cleanly handle this test case in adherence with proper TDD principles.

Comment: TDD is the approach and you can find multiple ways of doing it

Comment: Please post relevant code instead of linking it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: *"Is the negative test in this case even necessary or just overkill?"* the only valid authority for this decision is your requirements documentation. Does it tell how to deal with errors? is there an implicit expectation by the customer about error handling?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Question edited to comply. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good approach, IMHO, would be to start by writing the javadoc for your method. That is its specification.

It must tell what the method does, returns and throws.

`queryForObject()` specifies that it throws `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` if the query does not return exactly one row.

Your method should deal with the case where the ID doesn't exist in the database, too. It can throw the same exception, or throw another exception, or return null, or return an empty `Optional<Customer>` instead of `Customer`. That's **your** design choice.

Once you've made that choice, document it, and write tests that verify this contract:

1. when getting a customer that exists in the DB, check that the method indeed returns that customer
2. when getting a customer that does not exist in the DB, check that the method throws the right exception, or returns the right value, depending on your design choice.

Clearly testing with -1, and adding a special case for this specific identifier is wrong. Because -1 is just one of the huge number of IDs that don't exist in the database. The methodmust not make the test pass. The method must do what its specification says it does.